# I want simply print if i gave a input like 0 then it automatically gave me Monday. There is any easy solution with `date` & `strtodate`

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want simply print if i gave a input like 0 then it automatically gave me Monday. There is any easy solution with `date` & `strtodate`

I know i can be done with functions. I am very much curious to know how it will be work predefined function.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exactly are you trying to do? Are you saying you don't want to use `date` and `strtotime`?

Comment: I want to use date and strtotime

Comment: simply define an array and use it `$input =0;
$weeks = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday');
 echo $weeks[$input];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jddayofweek()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php) does this:

```
echo jddayofweek(0, 1); // Monday
```

The first parameter, `0`, is the day of the week you want, and the second parameter, `1`, specifies that you want it as a string.

More examples:

```
echo jddayofweek(1, 1); // Tuesday
echo jddayofweek(2, 1); // Wednesday
echo jddayofweek(3, 1); // Thursday
echo jddayofweek(4, 1); // Friday
echo jddayofweek(5, 1); // Saturday
echo jddayofweek(6, 1); // Sunday
```

[**See demo**](http://ideone.com/iUUS5y)